# Cannot change position of the MonthCalendar popup of the datetimepicker Winform control

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, pinvoke, datetimepicker

I'm currently developing a custom datetimepicker control that derives from the standard datetimepicker control.

The problem is I cannot change the position of the monthcalendar popup when dropped down.

Here is my code that shifts the monthcalendar popup control to the left by 50px and it works for the control but not the popup window below it:

```
private const int DTM_FIRST = 0x1000;
private const int DTM_GETMONTHCAL = (DTM_FIRST + 8);
private const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1;

[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr h, int msg, int param, int data);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, 
    int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs eventargs)
{
  IntPtr monthCalHandle = SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_GETMONTHCAL, 0, 0);
  if (monthCalHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
  {
    throw new Exception("Cannot get calendar control");
  }  

  bool success = SetWindowPos(monthCalHandle, IntPtr.Zero,
      -50, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);

  base.OnDropDown(eventargs);
}
```

Here is what it looks like from the above code. As you can see the control shifted to the left by 50px but not the popup window below it:

[image: Calendar control shifted to the left]

So I thought I should get hold of the parent popup window of the monthcalendar control and set it's position and this is what I did:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs eventargs)
{
  IntPtr monthCalHandle = SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_GETMONTHCAL, 0, 0);
  if (monthCalHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
  {
    throw new Exception("Cannot get calendar control");
  }  

  IntPtr parentHandle = GetParent(monthCalHandle);
  if (parentHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
  {
    throw new Exception("Cannot get calendar parent popup");
  }

  bool success = SetWindowPos(parentHandle, IntPtr.Zero,
      -50, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);

  base.OnDropDown(eventargs);
}
```

And nothing changed is what I get:

[image: No change]

**By the way**

No exceptions were thrown when I run the application. I am using VS 2015 Community and the project targets .NET v4.0.

Appreciate your kind advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your goal position?  To get the dropped-down part (the calendar) to be more centered underneath the drop-down field (the part showing the selected date)?

Comment: In my code I am trying to move the dropped-down part 50px to the left as a proof of concept.